# Navigating to Commonly/Recently Used Dirs, in Terminal (Unix/OS X)

Tags: macos, bash, unix

Would it be possible to save certain locations that I've used recently/commonly (like /folder/folder/folder/) so that I don't have to manually navigate through each dir between my current and destination dir?

Sort of like alt-tab, but for paths.  I'm on OS X, but perhaps this can be done using basic Unix skills?

Thanks!

Comment: You should vote up any answers to this question that you found helpful, and "accept" (checkmark) the one answer that best helped you. These actions help reward those who contributed their time to help you, they help future users of the site with similar questions find the best answer, they encourage people to answer your future questions, and they help _your_ reputation.

Comment: For the record, I don't think I had up-voting capability at the time of posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon [Z](https://github.com/rupa/z) and it has solved all of my dir-navigating issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you set up your shell to save commands history, using Ctrl+R hotkey may save you some time, which performs search of previously executed commands as you type. Another good thing to know is that most shells provide you with file/directory name completion if you press Tab key once/twice, which is also of great help.

**EDIT:** you can also make some symbolic links inside single (e.g. home) directory to quickly access directories. Use `ln -s <path to target file/directory> <path to link>` command. Target paths could either be relative or absolute.

Comment: Symbolically linking commonly used dirs in my home directory is a really good idea, and CTRL+R is very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way that works in most shells (but is slightly different for different shells) is the directory stack.  You can use `pushd` to push a directory, `popd` to pop the top directory from the stack, and `dirs` to move directories around and switch to directories in the middle of the stack.  I just checked, and the man page for `pushd` on Mac OS X is useless; use the man page for your shell (likely `bash`) and search for `pushd`, etc. there.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, you can add directories to the `CDPATH` variable. If you try to `cd` to a directory that doesn't begin with a slash then the directories listed in `CDPATH` are searched for a matching destination.

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh` there are a few options.

A shell can keep a stack of the most recent few directories you've `cd`'ed into if you use `setopt AUTO_PUSHD`.  With completion set up (`autoload -U compinit; compinit`), type `cd +` and press <kbd>tab</kbd>, then you'll get a numbered list:

```
~% cd /Library
/Library% cd /System/Library
/System/Library% cd +
1 -- /Library
2 -- /Users/nicholas
```

So the most recent directory is `+1`, etc.  (You can reverse this, as I do, with `setopt PUSHD_MINUS` so you use `-` instead of `+` and the most recent directory is `-1`).

Another option is directory hashing; you can create pseudo-"home directories" (`~whatever`).  Some of mine, for example:

```
  hash -d v=/Volumes
  hash -d a=/Volumes/BanjoArchive
  hash -d pep=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current
  hash -d sp=$(print /Library/Python/*/site-packages(On[1]))
```

So I can just type `cd ~pep` or `cd pep` (if unambiguous) or even `pep` (if `AUTO_CD` is set).  In situations other than `cd`, you can use the directory stack with `~` as well, e.g. `~+1` or `~-1`.

`zsh` can even replace shell variables after a `~` with the `AUTO_NAME_DIRS` option, though I don't use it because it would clutter the variable list.  Nevertheless, here's an example:

```
~%setopt AUTO_NAME_DIRS
~%v=/Volumes

~%cd ~v
~v%pwd
/Volumes
```

`zsh` also supports `cdpath` as one of the other answers mentions. For example, I have:

```
cdpath=($HOME /Volumes)
```

so I can just use the name of a mounted volume or directory in my home directory to `cd` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Either an `alias` (via placing it into your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` depending on setup):

```
alias godocs='cd /home/me/my_docs`
```

or `pushd/popd` as @Jeremiah suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "Cd Deluxe" for a greatly improved "change directory" command: http://www.plan10.com/cdd/.